# Will a DHCP server hand out leases to unrecognized vendor class identifiers?

Tags: ip, dhcp

Can a DHCP Client that sends option 60 in DISCOVER/REQUEST message get ip-settings (ACK) even if the DHCP server does not recognize the vendor?

i.e will the DHCP server hand out lease but omit vendor specific parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing prevents server from doing that. Especially given the separation between DISCOVER and REQUEST phases, as the server can answer with what it thinks is appropriate for the client and only if the client is satisfied with the OFFER will it send the REQUEST. So if the client really cares about some specific parameters, it can just ignore the "wrong" OFFER. And server shouldn't care at all.

Also, [RFC 2132](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132) specifically says that this information can be ignored:

> 9.13. Vendor class identifier
>
> ...
>
> Servers not equipped to interpret the class-specific information sent by a
> client MUST ignore it (although it may be reported). Servers that
> respond SHOULD only use option 43 to return the vendor-specific
> information to the client.